# how to traverse through the DOM object?

Tags: scripting, vbscript

I need to traverse through the DOM object and display the text in it without any duplicates.

Example:

```
<div>
      <div>hello
      <div>welcome</div>
      hai
     </div>
123
</div>
```

The output should be

```
hello
welcome
hai
123
```

How to implement this in VBScript?

Actually, I tried with recursion, but it does not seem to work correctly.

```
function traverse(allnode)

for each node in allnode
  if node.hasChildNodes then
      traverse(node.childNodes)
  else
      Msgbox node.nodeValue
  end if
end function
```

This function is printing the "text" for more than one times (i.e. for each `div` element). How to implement it in VBScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this HTML:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
   <div>
    hello
    <div>welcome</div>
    hai
   </div>
   123
  </div>
  <p>noli me tangere</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

in oDOM and calling this Sub

```
Sub traverseDom00(ndX, nInd)
  WScript.Echo Space(nInd), ndX.nodeName
  If ndX.hasChildNodes Then
     Dim ndY
     For Each ndY In ndX.childNodes
         traverseDom00 ndY, nInd + 1
     Next
  End If
  WScript.Echo Space(nInd), "/" & ndX.nodeName
End Sub
```

via `traverseDom00 oDOM, 0` results in

```
 #document
  HTML
   HEAD
    TITLE
    /TITLE
   /HEAD
   BODY
    DIV
     DIV
      #text
      /#text
      DIV
       #text
       /#text
      /DIV
      #text
      /#text
     /DIV
     #text
     /#text
    /DIV
    P
     #text
     /#text
    /P
   /BODY
  /HTML
 /#document
```

This Sub shows the basic structure for a recursive DOM traversal. If you compare this to your function (why a function?), you'll see that

1. you are missing a next
2. you have to check for having childNodes **before** you loop

Based on the traversal code structure, it's easy to come up with

```
Sub traverseDom01(ndX, aRes)
  If ndX.hasChildNodes Then
     Dim ndY
     For Each ndY In ndX.childNodes
         traverseDom01 ndY, aRes
     Next
  End If
  If "#text" = ndX.nodeName Then
     If "DIV" = ndX.parentNode.nodeName Then
        ReDim Preserve aRes(UBound(aRes) + 1)
        aRes(UBound(aRes)) = Trim(ndX.nodeValue)
     End If
  End If
End Sub
```

to collect the texts that are children of a DIV. Called via

```
  Dim aDTs : aDTs = Array()
  traverseDom01 oDOM, aDTs
  WScript.Echo "|" & Join(aDTs, "|") & "|"
```

the result is

```
|hello|welcome|hai|123|
```